# During a Realm migration, how can I do a many-to-one migration?

Tags: objective-c, swift, realm, realm-migration

Here's what I mean.

Let's say we have numerous pieces of data, and they each have a date.

```
a: 2017/04/20
b: 2017/04/23
c: 2017/04/29
d: 2017/05/02
e: 2017/05/04
```

Our goal going forward is to stop storing data this way, we only want to store aggregated data per month. So we want to aggregate data a&b&c in our example for month `04`, and aggregate data d&e in month `05`.

So in the end we just want 2 pieces of data.

Is it reasonable to do this in a migration, or is it not really the place, or possibly not even possible?

Essentially in `[migration enumerateObjects:Data.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {` we would need to go in and figure out the month of the data, and keep a running total. We would need some command letting realm to not migrate that particular piece of data at this moment (as we don't want to until the aggregation is complete). However, the only way we know is when we move from c to d, or month 04 to 05. At that point, we know we have our running-tally/aggregated-data... and I'm guessing it's too late to now migrate.

Does anyone know if something like this is possible? I'm guessing not, it doesn't really make sense... but maybe someone out there knows that it definitely doesn't work or has a way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do it in a migration.

You can iterate through all of the objects in a Realm file multiple times, so it *should* simply be a matter of iterating through all of the objects, aggregating the values of each month, and then iterating through the list a second time to apply the new values. You can also delete objects inside migration blocks, so you could also ensure only one object per month remains:

```
id migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {

    // Use a dictionary to store the aggregate values.
    // Dictionary keys must be unique, so they can be used to aggregate multiple values for a month.
   NSMutableDictionary *months = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

   //Loop through each object to extract and aggregate the data for each month
   [migration enumerateObjects:Data.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {

        // Extract the month value from the date in this object
        NSDate *date = newObject["date"]; // Properties can be retrieved from RLMObject via KVC
        NSInteger month = date.month.intValue; // Extract the month from that date

        // Track if this was the first entry for this specific month
        BOOL firstTime = ([months.allKeys indexOfObject:@(month)] == NSNotFound);

        // Aggregate the value of month with the value stored in the dictionary
        NSInteger aggregateValue = months[@(month)].intValue;
        aggregateValue += date; // Add the month's information to the aggregate
        months[@(month)] = @(aggregateValue);

        // If this isn't the first object, we don't need it in Realm anymore, so delete it
        if (!firstTime) {
            [migration deleteObject:newObject];
        }
    }];

    // At this point, `months` will contain our aggregate values, and the Realm database
    // only has one object per month now.

    // Loop through all the objects again so we can add in the aggregate values
    [migration enumerateObjects:Data.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
        NSDate *date = newObject["date"];
        NSInteger month = date.month.intValue;

        // Copy in the aggregate value
        newObject["date"] = months[@(month)];
    }];
}
```

That being said, migrations are designed for when the actual schema of your database changes. In this case, it looks like your schema isn't changing, but simply the granularity of the data you want to store is.

If that's the case, it might be more appropriate for you to write your own helper function that runs at the start of your app, checks to see if your data has been aggregated yet, and performs the aggregation if it detects it isn't.